# How to modify this python opencv program to get xy coordinates from thresholded image

Tags: python, c++, opencv, numpy

I have an opencv program to track a blue object  here

Can someone modify it to find center of the object tracked from webcam after thresholding it to a binary image

PS: I wan this programto work with a webcam not an image

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
while(True):
ret, frame = cap.read()  
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_blue = np.array([110,50,50])
upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255])
mask = cv2.inRange(gray, lower_blue, upper_blue)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)
# Display the resulting frame
cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
cv2.imshow('res',res)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
break
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I would like to find the center ie xy coordinates of the white blob from threshold image from webcam

I have code  that i used for finding xy cordinates of a threshold image

*I want to modify it for live video from webcam*

**HERE is the code to find co-ordinates of a binary image**

```
for y in xrange(img.size[1]):
for x in xrange(img.size[0]):
if pixels[x, y] == 0:
xlist.append(x)
ylist.append(y)
xleft = min(xlist)
xright = max(xlist)
ytop = min(ylist)
ybot = max(ylist)
xax = (xleft+xright)/2
yax = (ytop+ybot)/2
```

**can someone combian this 2 codes to make it work for live feed from webcam**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cv2.findContours) after the bitwise_and, then get the boundingRect (or the moments) for the contour to get the x,y location.

and forget about your "find co-ordinates of a binary image" idea. (no, you *don't* want to reinvent 'connected components'. use the builtin stuff instead)

Comment: i used findContours() but when i store it to an array say cnt=contours[4] , its says "array index out of bound"!!!!! , can someone add that particular code for finding xyy coordinates using findContours() to the above pgm??

Comment: ofc you've got to check the len(contours) befoer you can access an item.

Comment: and no, sorry, i won't write your program.

Comment: I used moments ,GetSpacialmoments() tofind the co-ordinates!!! thanks for the support